# Send POST request with empty response

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

I am trying to get response form my API via CURL, the method needs to get user data via XML and than returns XML with response data.
I get nothing back. API works well, when I try the same request elsewhere than in PHP, it works. My API requires the data to be sent in application/xml Content-Type.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```php
<?php
    $request="https://api.mydomain.com/operation/v1/rest/xml/user/authenticate";
    $xml_data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
               <userCredentials>
                    <userName>name</userName>
                    <password>password</password>
               </userCredentials>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-type: application/xml");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<b>Request:</b> $request <br/>";
    echo "<b>Response:</b><pre>".$output."</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Does you API get the data you sent via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Comment: no, it doesn't. When I do just the plain read from other API methods, it returns what I need.

Comment: does text/xml in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER change anything?

Comment: Not to link to the obvious, but why don't you wrap your XML output into http://php.net/htmlspecialchars - if you output HTML you need to escape XML to have it visible. HTML by default hides all unknown tags.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, quick guess (lengthy comment):

```
echo "<b>Response:</b><pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

This will output the XML unescaped. Your browser will not display anything inside the browser window, but you should be fine to see something when you view the source of the page.